# Markdown (or Textile) editor for Joomla

Tags: joomla, text-editor, markdown

I wonder whether there's any markdown editor similar to one used on StackExchange sites that's pluggable into Joomla CMS?

Regular users tend to use rich WYSIWYG as they use Word. They set too many styles which makes the whole page ugly. Markdown editors on the other hand allow writing rich content that will end up in style of the site.

Textile editor welcome as well, but less desired.

**So are there any?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not allowed to *post a link*, but if you search for `yoonique markdown extra editor joomla` you should be able to find one. It is not exactly wysiwyg, but it has a preview pane, which updates have after every RETURN. You can also set an option to filter the `markdown extra` output with htmlawed.

[edit]
It looks like I am actually able to post a link

[markdown editor for joomla](http://yoonique.net/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=item&item_id=21)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is only half an answer, but it may solve your problem.

Most of the wysiwyg editor on Joomla (surely TinyMCE, JCE) can be configured to show only certain buttons on the toolbar; that means you can end up with the same set of button as the one used on this very site.

So, yes: there are some; the common wysiwyg editors, adequately configured.

Comment: Configuring WYSIWYG isn't exactly what I'm after because you still have to do selects, click on buttons etc. You can't really format your text using just simple typing (well you can to some extent, but it's definitelly not the same). Markdown and Textile produce very clean and valid HTML, while WYSIWYG editors don't.

Comment: Sure, they are different things, and that is why i said it was only "half an answer". I still think you can reduce the "damage" provoked by a WYSIWYG just by hiding down most of its buttons. Back to your original question, i never used or seen such kind of editors for Joomla, i just found this via Google: http://nigelball.org/2009/03/06/joomla-textile-plugin